# How can I add column to prettytable as a first column

Tags: python

I have some table `x` which I have done with prettytable module. Now I want to add a column to it, but I want it to be added as a first column, how can I do that?

Method `add_column` puts my column on the last spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the [documentation](https://ptable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) there are two ways. You can simply regenerate the table from scratch, making sure you add the column in question first.

The second possibility is to access the data structures making up the PrettyTable and modifying them manually. Beware that any mistake made this way **will not** be caught by the validation build around the default `add_column` function.

If we have a table

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable()
x.field_names = ["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"]
x.add_row(["Adelaide",1295, 1158259, 600.5])
x.add_row(["Brisbane",5905, 1857594, 1146.4])
x.add_row(["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7])
x.add_row(["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5])
x.add_row(["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8])
x.add_row(["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9])
x.add_row(["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4])

print(x)

+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| City name | Area | Population | Annual Rainfall |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
|  Adelaide | 1295 |  1158259   |      600.5      |
|  Brisbane | 5905 |  1857594   |      1146.4     |
|   Darwin  | 112  |   120900   |      1714.7     |
|   Hobart  | 1357 |   205556   |      619.5      |
|   Sydney  | 2058 |  4336374   |      1214.8     |
| Melbourne | 1566 |  3806092   |      646.9      |
|   Perth   | 5386 |  1554769   |      869.4      |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
```

To insert a column at the beginning

```
fieldname = 'Number'
x._field_names.insert(0, fieldname) 
x._align[fieldname] = 'c' 
x._valign[fieldname] = 't' 
for i, _ in enumerate(x._rows): 
    x._rows[i].insert(0, i) 

print(x)

+--------+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| Number | City name | Area | Population | Annual Rainfall |
+--------+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
|   0    |  Adelaide | 1295 |  1158259   |      600.5      |
|   1    |  Brisbane | 5905 |  1857594   |      1146.4     |
|   2    |   Darwin  | 112  |   120900   |      1714.7     |
|   3    |   Hobart  | 1357 |   205556   |      619.5      |
|   4    |   Sydney  | 2058 |  4336374   |      1214.8     |
|   5    | Melbourne | 1566 |  3806092   |      646.9      |
|   6    |   Perth   | 5386 |  1554769   |      869.4      |
+--------+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
```

Now you can use my example on how I added the field `Number` to add a field of your choice.

I would still highly recommend you process the data *before* creating the table and only then dealing with PrettyTable.

Comment: First one is problematic for me, because I create another columns with loops over rows. And the other one seems not to be working, its output does not change order :(

Comment: You are correct, the second option did not work Fortunately I found a way to solve your problem and put that in my edited answer in stead of the not working solution.